# Picking a random string from an array

Tags: php, html, random, strpos

Trying to get this code to work. It might be easier to show what I'm trying to do, and what is missing:

```
<?php
    $array=array(
        "something",
        "something else"
    );
    /*pick a random entry in the array and store it as $output*/;
    if(strpos($output,"else") !== false){
        //do stuff;
    }
    echo "<div>";
    echo $output
    echo "</div>"
?>
```

As you can see, I'm having trouble trying to store a random entry in `$output`. What I want to do is to pick a random entry from the array, run a strpos on the result to do additional things if the conditions are met, and then output the same random entry between the divs.

EDIT: In case it's not clear, the line commented with `/*` and `*/` is supposed to be a 'fill in the blank' line, and not a 'this comment refers to the lines of code below' comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand) to get a random entry.

```
$output = $array[array_rand($array)];
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in different random results if $output is called in two different places?

Comment: @Hiigaran: Nope. `array_rand()` will not be called each time you `echo` it somewhere. Proof: https://eval.in/136389

Comment: I'll give it a try and see how it goes, then.

Answer (score 2):

Generate a random number between zero and one less than the length of the array, use that as the array index to get a random item from the array.

```
<?php
$output = $array[rand(0, count($array)-1];
```